# PR2 controller joint: control 2 joints with one motor

Tags: ros, joint, urdf, transmission, pr2-controllers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In our robotics hand, I have to control 2 joints with one motor: the distal and middle joints are mecanically linked together, so you issue a command to a "super joint" which moves both of them (let's call this joint J0).

We have one sensor in each joint (J1 and J2): we add both joint calibrated values to compute the J0 position. It's not possible to move those joints individually.

For the time being my model only contains the "normal" joints (J1 and J2). The problem I have is that the J0 is then not defined, so it's not possible to control it.

What would be the best way to solve my problem?

I was thinking about adding a "dummy" joint J0 in the model (with really small links, so it's not visible / doesn't add collision where it shouldn't), but I guess there must be a better way of doing that. Any help greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10406/pr2-controller-joint:-control-2-joints-with-one-motor/) by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1620 on 2011-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

take wrist transmission for example, in **propagatePosition**, you should update all joint values by writing them back into your joint state **js[]** vector.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-09-11**:
This thread is related to the question as well: http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/Custom-transmission-td1688187.html

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use a transmission to do this.  An example is the PR2 gripper, one actuator, several moving parts.  Hopefully someone else can give you a more complete answer and some links.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-06-27**:
Thanks Tully, I'll take a look at it (for future reference, the pr2_gripper is in pr2_description/urdf/gripper_v0, and the transmission in pr2_mechanism_model/src/pr2_gripper_transmission.cpp )